# How can I add an border to a span at an offset

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

But so far I managed to do this

[image]

I am not able to position the transformed square to the left, and I dont know how to create the outer border.

I thought of adding a margin to it but it did not work.

```css
:root {
  --primary: #0098fa;
  --accent: #effaff;
  --dark: #394e67;
  --darker: #2f3640;
}

.ts-divider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  color: var(--primary);
}

.ts-divider:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  opacity: .6;
}

.ts-divider span:before {
  width: 70.75%;
  height: 70.75%;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  border: 1px solid var(--darker);
}

.ts-divider span::after {
  width: 41%;
  height: 41%;
  left: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  background-color: var(--darker);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
}
```

```html
<span class="ts-divider">
                    <span></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave my attempt using single element with background and border color:

```css
:root {
  --primary: #0098fa;
  --accent: #effaff;
  --dark: #394e67;
  --darker: #2f3640;
  
  --line-length: 200px;
  --box-size: 40px;
  --inner-box-size: 24px;
  --spacing: calc( var(--box-size) - var(--inner-box-size));
  --offset: calc( var(--spacing) / 2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ts-divider {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--line-length);
  height: var(--box-size);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--primary);
}

.ts-divider::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
  background-color: var(--dark);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.ts-divider::after {
  --top-offset: calc(50% + var(--offset));
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--inner-box-size);
  height: var(--inner-box-size);
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--top-offset);
  left: var(--offset);
  background-color: var(--primary);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ts-divider"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property to have multiple borders. You can also remove the z-index on the `:after` pseudo element. I have highlighted the changes through comments.

```css
:root {
  --primary: #7a6450;
  --accent: #effaff;
  --dark: #7a6450;
  --darker: #7a6450;
}

body {
  background: #0e1317;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ts-divider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 63px;
  height: 63px;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  color: var(--primary);
}

.ts-divider:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 1; Removed */
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 17.5px; /* Manual adjustment according to your code */
  background-color: currentColor;
  opacity: .6;
}

.ts-divider span:before {
  width: 70.75%;
  height: 70.75%;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  border: 1px solid var(--darker);
}

.ts-divider span::after {
  width: 41%;
  height: 41%;
  left: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  background-color: var(--darker);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #0e1317, 0 0 0px 10px var(--darker); /* First box-shdoaw with the background color and second one with the box color. 5 and 10 are values of their spread radius so you can make use of the offset using that. */
}
```

```html
<span class="ts-divider">
     <span></span>
</span>
```